Is onSuccess Callback is removed from query (tRPC)?
app/auth-callback/page.tsx
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import React from 'react'
import { trpc } from '../_trpc/client'

const Page = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  
  const searchParmas = useSearchParams()
  const origin = searchParmas.get('origin')
 
  const {data,isLoading} = trpc.authcallback.useQuery( undefined, {
    onSuccess:({success})=>{
      if(success){
        router.push('/dashboard')
      }
    }
  }) 
}

export default Page

api endpoint (trpc/index.ts)
import { getKindeServerSession } from '@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server';
import { publicProcedure, router } from './trpc';
import { TRPCError } from '@trpc/server';

export const appRouter = router({
  authcallback: publicProcedure.query( async ()=>{
    const {getUser} = getKindeServerSession()
    const user = await getUser()
    
    if(!user?.id || !user?.email) {
      throw new TRPCError({code:"UNAUTHORIZED"})
    }
    return {success:true}
  })
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;

Hello, In the above code i want to access the success response from my api endpoint and for this i am using tRPC and @tanstack/react-query but i am not able to access the callback (onSuccess).
How i can access it or an alternative option that helps me out.
Success is a boolean;

Hey, would this article help? https://tkdodo.eu/blog/breaking-react-querys-api-on-purpose



'use client'

import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { trpc } from '../_trpc/client'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default async function AuthCallback () {
  const router = useRouter()

  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
  const origin = searchParams.get('origin')

  const { data, error } = trpc.authCallback.useQuery(undefined, {
    retry: true,
    retryDelay: 500
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data?.success === true) {
      router.push((origin != null) ? `/${origin}` : '/dashboard')
      return
    }

    if (error?.data?.code === 'UNAUTHORIZED') {
      router.push('/sign-in')
    }
  }, [data, error])

  return (
    <div className='w-full mt-24 flex justify-center'>
      <div className='flex flex-col items-center gap-2'>
        <h3 className='font-semibold text-xl'>
          Setting up your account...
        </h3>
        <p>You will be redirected automatically.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
